# iOS7 nav bar translucent = NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a background image, the same image in all views, but the nav bar traslucent is set by default to YES and the background is not homogeneous. I tried various solutions but nothing change :(

my AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

my AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >>16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: UIColorFromRGB(0x45312a)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];

NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

but in the line:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

give me these error: Property 'navigationController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add a property on your application delegate called navigationController to call self.navigationController

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that in your root view controller

```
//inside the root view controller
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
}
```

Also you can toggle translucent in the interface builder. Select your Navigation Controller then in the **Document Outline** select the Navigation Bar and just change it in the **Attributes Inspector**

[image: Attributes Inspector Navigation Bar]

Comment: I don't have the same screen.. http://oi58.tinypic.com/69houx.jpg
but the code works fine! Thanks! After 3 hours of trying and searching!

Answer (score 2):

Because the AppDelegate is not a UINavigation Controller. You can do what you done on previous lines is to set the navigationbar appearance globally.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: Curious if this would work, this is called as a Class method, doesn't this need to be called on the object instance?

Comment: I have tried this options but give me this error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter:'

Answer (score -2):

try this for ios 7

```
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of what this code does please?