# Can I set a navigationBar transparent in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, navigation

I have several UIViewControllers in a UITabBarController.

In each UIViewController's viewDidLoad method I include this line:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Is there a setting in Storyboard that can do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the navigation bar of the navigation controller, just select it in the document outline, check this [iOS7 nav bar translucent = NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734399/ios7-nav-bar-translucent-no/21734704#21734704)

Comment: Big thanks. My Navigation Controller's Navigation Bar was so far away (on my Storyboard) from my page of tabs I never thought to look there! Making this one change in Storyboard is better than remembering to add a line of code in every view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do this on storyboard (Xcode 8, iOS 10), instead I used a custom navigationBar and overriding the awakeFromNib:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.translucent = YES;
}
```