# Set Statusbar color to same as Nav Bar

Tags: ios, statusbar, color-picker

I want the Status Bar of my app to have the exact same color as my Navigation Bar. The way I found to change the color of the Status Bar was just by creating a view in the size of the Status Bar and change the background color.

However even though I use the color picker from the Nav bar to set the color of the view I get 2 totally different colors as seen in the picture below.
[image]

I've tried mixing with the color picker, changing opacity etc, however I'm never able to hit the correct color. Any ideas on how I can get the exact same color for the status bar?

Comment: Try setting your nav bars translucent property to no -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734399/ios7-nav-bar-translucent-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the `UIStatusBar` is automatically set to match the color of the `UINavigationBar` when you set the value of `self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor`. Is there a reason you need to set them separately?

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me.  barTintColor is set successfully to light gray, but status bar remains white.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Create an UIImage containing only the color you want with a size of 64x1. You could render that image in code.
2. Set the image as a background image for the navigationBar. Something like:
   navigationController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)