# iPhone not displaying accurate color

Tags: ios, colors, statusbar

I'm working on a simple `WebView` app where I want the `Statusbar` to be the same color as the `Taskbar` from the website.

What I did was setting the background color of the `View` to the same color as the `Taskbar`by using the color picker. However when I run the app I'm getting a completely different color as you can see below:
[image]

These are the settings for the view:

[image]

The color code of the Taskbar is: #242424
However the color code the statusbar gets is: #1b1b1b even though I've selected the #242424 color via the color picker.

Why does it seem to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode Colour picker not pick exact same colour. Try this macro(set your colour code)

```
#define CODE_1_COLOR   [UIColor colorWithRed:(140.0f/255.0f) green:(132.0f/255.0f) blue:(124.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]
```

Also take care about Translucent property in case of navigation bar

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the translucency of the bar, as explained in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30385517/4151918) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28560220/4151918).

You also have to consider that the view extends under the translucent bar, and the view's background color will slightly change the appearance of any translucent bars above it, because of the visual effect used by the bar.

You may want to not set a specific color for the status bar, and let it inherit the bar's color, to give the task bar and status bar a uniform appearance.

Comment: This would explain it. Execpt when I expand the webview to reach under the Statusbar the color is accurate as the taskbar from the webpage appears under the statusbar.